# How to submit null options using Polkadot.js/api?

Tags: polkadot-js

For queries such as `api.query.identity.indentityOf(AccountID32)` it is possible within Polkadot.JS.org/apps to include or not include a parameter:

[image: Option not included]

[image: Option included]

I would like to do the same via typescript but I'm unable to determine the right syntax.  I have tried:

- api.query.identity.identityOf()
- api.query.identity.identityOf(null)
- api.query.identity.identityOf(undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying all entries of a map can be done with the `.entries()` function:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const identities = await api.query.identity.identityOf.entries();

identities.forEach(([key, identity]) => {
      console.log(key.toHuman(), identity.toHuman());
});
```

In this case, however, you probably want to use the `entriesPaged` function since it are so many entries and the probably cannot be loaded at once:

```js
... // Setup same as above

const PAGE_SIZE = 50;
let last_key = null;
let identities = [];

for (;;) {
    const new_identities = await api.query.identity.identityOf.entriesPaged({ args: [], pageSize: PAGE_SIZE, startKey: last_key });
    console.log(`Loading ${new_identities.length} more identities…`);
    identities = identities.concat(new_identities);
    if (new_identities.length < PAGE_SIZE) {
        console.log(`Done! Loaded ${identities.length} identities.`);
        break;
    }
    last_key = new_identities[new_identities.length - 1][0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! This is exactly what I was looking for!